# Create a VST to access Audio Unit?

Tags: audio

I have audio software that only uses VST plug-ins, not Apple's Audio Units. Does anyone know if it might be feasible to create a VST that accesses Audio Units? Particularly, Apple's own DSL Midi sounds.

Comment: AFAIK not particularly; what about using [ReWire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReWire_(software_protocol)) or something similar to just route the audio using software from Logic/Mainstage into whatever other program you're using?

Comment: Yes, passing the MIDI out to Logic and setting up the Audio Units there will work, though it's twice the effort for me and the computer!

Comment: Hrm, fair. Not sure I immediately see an easier solution, though your question is quite interesting.